# I/O or faulty hard disk error during ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, hard-drive

I have two sata hard disk installed in my desktop. When i try to install ubuntu in /dev/sda it shows an error at the end of installation process. Error: "I/O or faulty hard disk or faulty medium" something like this.

I tried to install with several ubuntu cd/dvd, all shows the same error. I have successfully installed fedora on the same partition. I tried to read other DVD/CD to check that my DVD drive is ok.

I found that i have no problem in DVD drive, installation CD/DVD. Now problem is hard disk. Fedora does not show any error or warning about hard disk. And here is the partition table of my HDD:

[image]

I can not figure out what the actual problem. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post any error logs? The live system and ubiquity should also generate logs. Maybe even running ubiquity from a terminal will make those error messages appear in the terminal. Did you also try an alternate install CD?

Comment: sorry i can't understand. It shows problem in installation process. How could i collect log during installation?

Comment: Open the disk utility and check the drive's SMART status.

Comment: @psusi No error in SMART test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your installation is getting all the way to the end then your disk isn't bad. There's something about that partition layout that is likely spooking the installation of grub.

That's an awfully complex partition layout on your first disk so I'm not surprised that you're having problems.

I would suggest that you re-configure the installation to install grub to a partition, and not the Master Boot Record (MBR). This should be available in the standard image installer, if not, download the alternative installer image which gives you much more control over the installation process.